# Contacts Pocket PC - WM 5.0 - C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

Hello Im new in creating simple programs in mobile .net. So my question is,
is it possible for me to get all the contacts stored in an emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Yup you can query the contacts list using PocketOutlook API, you have to add a reference to Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook assembly then use this snippet of code

```
OutlookSession session = new OutlookSession();
ContactCollection contacts = session.Contacts.Items;
foreach (Contact contact in contacts)
{ 
   // Supposing that lstContacts is a ListBox on a form
   lstContacts.Items.Add(contact.FirstName + contact.LastName);
}
```